# ManyToOne Relationship with the same entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity

```
@Entity
class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
//Other fields 

}
```

Every employee has a superVisor, which is basically related to the same table.

How can I define the relationship in Spring Jpa?

```
 @Entity
    class Employee {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id; 
        @ManyToOne
        private Employee firstLevelSupervisor; 


        
    //Other fields 
    
    }
```

I tried something like that but I am getting either recursive error or ambiguity error.

Comment: Does this issue really have to do with JPA or is the Error to do with JSON/REST? There should be no issue here as long as you don't have an employee pointing at itself - you cannot be your own supervisor as you need much more to tell your JSON serializer how to turn a recursive reference into JSON and prevent a stackoverflowException

Comment: Using roles table will be a better design and idea in this case.